# UCMA 4.0 in Skype for Business in Office 365

Tags: .net, lync, ucma, skype-for-business

I have a .NET solution developed with the help of UCMA 4.0 libraries to get skype presence and contact information from on-premises Lync server 2010. Now my organization is implementing Skype for Business in Office 365.

I would like to know if my existing UCMA 4.0 solution will work with new Skype for Business in Office 365?

Answer (score 0):

Skype online does not support UCMA applications.  There is no workaround or alternate SDK to support this.

AFAIK Microsoft are moving all there main SDK's over to web SDK to do the same or similar features.  Currently we are in a waiting game to see what they release as a replacement for UCMA for the web.

You can see a start to this with the Skype Web SDK (not released yet) to take over the client SDK / userendpoint part of UCMA.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/skypewebsdk

Update:
People have been getting Office 365 users to access on-premise UCMA applications via the edge server.  See the [Lync Development blog](http://blog.greenl.ee/2015/01/15/ucma-office-365/) for details.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can we use UCWA for O365?